# How to remove cursor pointer from d3 Pie chart

Tags: d3.js, pie-chart, c3

Is there an option that disables the "cursor: pointer" style from the c3|d3 pie chart?
I simply display slices and on hover just show the % percentage and a label, do not need the pointer because it is misunderstood as a link to somewhere, yet it is the default cursor...

Update 1:
I found a workaround, but it does not answer my question..

```
onrendered: function () { $('#my_chart_id .c3-shape').css('cursor', 'default'); }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the most straight-forward thing to do would be to use D3 to select each arc of the pie and change the cursor style, like this:

```
d3.selectAll(".c3-arc").style("cursor", "auto");
```

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/henbox/k9Dbf/270/

Cursor style options here: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_cursor.asp

Comment: Thank you very much Henry, i will upvote it, though its not actually a d3 option. In my update you may see a similar approach, which i think is better cause it will run even if the chart is somehow re-rendered.

Comment: @cnom: The cursor's appearance is set using a css rule. By default this is set by the library to `pointer` which shows the result you don't like. Since there is no built-in function in C3/D3 to explicitly set the cursor, this answer is pretty much the best you can get using pure D3. If you are concerned about re-rendering you might as well move this css rule from your code to the external stylesheet. I have updated the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k9Dbf/271/) to show this alternative approach.

Comment: @autocumulus Good shout using `!important` to ensure the setting overrides the default c3 css. I'd forgotten you could do that

Comment: @altocumulus This is a nice approach but with the problem that this could spoil other piecharts in the site (where the pointer is needed). Of course you could say that I make the css selector more specific by defining the id of each graph I want it on, but then it would be bad programming, i guess..

Comment: @cnom You have all the flexibility of CSS selectors at your hands. You could easily specify which charts will be affected by using a more specific selector like `#mychartid .c3-arc` or by giving a marker class to charts you want to behave differently.

Answer (score 2):

Via CSS override:

```
.c3-shape {
  cursor: default !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've used a css override that targets all (our) c3 instances:

```
.c3-event-rect {
  cursor: default !important;
}
```